# How to make a non-blocking, non-modal QMessageBox?

Tags: qt

How do I make a non-blocking, non-modal dialog equivalent to [QMessageBox::information](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmessagebox.html#information)?

Answer (score 35):

What do you mean by "unblocking"? Non-modal? Or one that doesn't block the execution until the user clicks ok? In both cases you'll need to create a QMessageBox manually instead of using the convenient static methods like QMessageBox::critical() etc.

In both cases, your friends are `QDialog::open()` and `QMessageBox::open( QObject*, const char* )`:

```
void MyWidget::someMethod() {
   ...
   QMessageBox* msgBox = new QMessageBox( this );
   msgBox->setAttribute( Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose ); //makes sure the msgbox is deleted automatically when closed
   msgBox->setStandardButtons( QMessageBox::Ok );
   msgBox->setWindowTitle( tr("Error") );
   msgBox->setText( tr("Something happened!") );
   msgBox->setIcon...
   ...
   msgBox->setModal( false ); // if you want it non-modal
   msgBox->open( this, SLOT(msgBoxClosed(QAbstractButton*)) );

   //... do something else, without blocking
}

void MyWidget::msgBoxClosed(QAbstractButton*) {
   //react on button click (usually only needed when there > 1 buttons)
}
```

Of course you can wrap that in your own helper functions so you don't have to duplicate it all over your code.

Comment: Thnks alot..I am looking 4 same thing.

Comment: This does not provide a true nonmodal dialog QMessageBox!