# Which button is pressed in a non-blocking QMessageBox?

Tags: qt, qmessagebox

I'm trying to make a non-blocking `QMessageBox` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211490/how-to-make-unblocking-qmessagebox).

In the slot `msgBoxClosed()` I only get a `QAbstractButton*` back, so how can I check which of the buttons (`QMessageBox::Yes`, `QMessageBox::No`) was pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following function to determine the button `QMessageBox::standardButton(QAbstractButton *button)`. For example:

```
StandardButton btn = msgBox->standardButton(button)
if (btn == QMessageBox::Ok) {
    [..]
}
```